# Javascript backwards date, reverse?

Tags: javascript, reverse

does anybody know How I could reverse the date that I have in javascript?

I have a created date of files from google drive which I pulled using the google drive api, however the date is reverse.

2014-02-25

I would like, 25-02-2014 (dd/mm/yyyy)

```
var date = resp.createdDate;
date = date.substring(0, date.length - 14)
```

This is my code, i trimmed the end off, because it came with time etc.

my output is currently : 2014-02-25

Im unsure how I could do this and im sure its simple!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
> "2014-02-25".split('-').reverse().join('-')
"25-02-2014"
```

Comment: I changed, 2014-02-25.split to  date.split("-") etc.. and It didnt seem to work.

Comment: What type is `date`? This only works on strings of the given format. It will not work on `Date` objects.

Comment: Ahh nvm I fixed it with date = date.split etc.. :)

Comment: @DanD. Its type is String!